# Is this comparison correct

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

This is based on an exercise that appears on the [Twilio Studio Tutorial Page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/build-a-chatbot-with-studio).  I decided to change the demo from a cafe to a cantina.

When the user requests something not on the menu, it's supposed to place a call to the user.  This has not worked, no call is placed.  I decided to put a block in to let the user know to expect a call, but that's not working either.

[image: Twilio Split on Call Block]

Comment: Did you publish the latest Studio Flow (something that gets me often). If so, did you look at the Execution Logs for that particular flow, to see what is going on? (is is on the left side of the screen when viewing the Studio canvas). The comparison to multiple values separated by commas doesn't look correct. Did you find that syntax in the documentation? Looks like "Matches Any Of" is the one you want - https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Alan points out in the comment, your widget is currently set test if the value is "equal_to y,yes,Y,Yes". But the value is probably only going to be one of those strings. Instead of testing that the value is "equal_to" you should be testing that it "Matches any of".

Try updating to that and let me know if that helps.

Comment: That did it!
Thanks!